# Chrome doesn't stop loading while FireFox doesn't have any problems

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, video

So I have a huge problem with Chrome.
I have a site that includes several videos with the `<video>` Tag of HTML 5. In Chrome the entire page doesn't seem to stop loading. The loading spinning circle is always spinning and it doesn't load content. If you click on some videos it will randomly load the rest of the content and the spinning circle will stop and get replaced by the favicon.
The strange thing however is that FireFox and even IE11 do load the page completly and with all the content.
After some investigation I found 2 videos causing this loading loop. If I comment these videos the page will load and everything is fine.
I checked if the videos are corrupt or damaged but they aren't.
So did anyone else have similar issues regarding videos in Chrome and how did you fix them?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page or to one of the problem videos?

Comment: @Mick Sorry this is not possible because of very sensible information about unreleased products... I am really sorry...

Comment: One way to approach this is to substitute these videos for similar format videos from the web, i.e. ones you cand find on the web with no sensitive information or licence restrictions, and if you see the same problem then provide a link to one of these videos. This allows people investigate whether the issue is with the format of the video (which causes quite a few browser video issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is a strange behaviour that's inconsistent across browsers.
If you don't set a `preload`value to the `video` tag Chrome does preload the videos while FireFox doesn't.
Taking some values from [this source](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/) it's actually quite significant. Chrome preloads 25s of the video while FireFox and even Internet Explorer don't preload anything.